# How to return the top last 3 dates in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with lots of fields in sql server

I need a query to return (in the same row!) the **top last 3 dates** (dates can have large gaps between them)

ie:

```
2012/01/20

2012/01/18

2012/01/12

2012/01/10

2012/01/04
```

Comment: Did the suggestion help?

Answer (score 1):

Try...

```
SELECT top 3 fields 
FROM table
ORDER By dateField Desc
```

Take a look at the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/85520/7) to get them in the same row

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (dt datetime)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ( [dt])
VALUES
    (getdate()-1),
(getdate()-2),
(getdate()-3),
(getdate()-4)

;

SELECT 
  STUFF((
    SELECT top 3 ', ' + convert(varchar(12), t.dt)
    FROM Table1 t
Order by dt desc
    FOR XML PATH (''))
  ,1,2,'') AS Dates
```

Answer (score 1):

Question and database structure a little vague but cant you just SELECT with a LIMIT statement and an ORDRR BY?

Eg.

SELECT TOP 3 table.date_field FROM table ORDER BY table.date_field DESC